# Typescript: Trouble finding proper type inside multiple (Firebase related) libraries

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-cli

I'm having trouble finding the right typings for Firebase because of the number of libraries it seems to pull types from. In that respect it is probably a good problem spacce to learn this issue from though.

I'm using Phpstorm 2019.3, I understand VSCode has much better typing assistance.

Here is the method:

```
  protected buildQueryUpToWhereClauseChain(priorQuery: any, whereClauses: WhereDefinition[]): FirebaseFirestore.Query {

    // = by default. overridden if meets condition
    let preparedWheresQuery: FirebaseFirestore.Query = priorQuery;
    if (whereClauses.length > 0) {
      preparedWheresQuery = whereClauses
        .reduce((accumulatedQuery, {column, operator, value}) => {
          return accumulatedQuery.where(column, operator, value);
        }, priorQuery);

    }

    return preparedWheresQuery;
  }
```

Test on extended class of above:

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

test('builds .where() query', () => {
    const openFirestoreConnection = new OpenFirestoreConnection('testdomain.shopify.com', createTestDatabase(null));

    const startingQuery = openFirestoreConnection.database
      .collection("collectionName")
      .where("storeId", "==", openFirestoreConnection.shopDomain);

    const whereClauses: WhereDefinition[] = [{
      column: "testColumn"
      , operator: '=='
      , value: "testValue"
    }, {
      column: "testColumn2"
      , operator: '<='
      , value: "testValue2"
    }];

    const builtQuery = openFirestoreConnection.buildQueryUpToWhereClauseChain(startingQuery, whereClauses);

// admin is from firebase-admin library
// Expected constructor: Query. Received constructor: Query
    expect(builtQuery).toBeInstanceOf(admin.firestore.Query);

// this one is from "firebase" library as documented here
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.html#where
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query.html
// Expected constructor: PublicConstructor. Received constructor: Query
//     expect(builtQuery).toBeInstanceOf(firebase.firestore.Query);
  });
```

If anyone could explain how to find the proper typing in instances like this I would appreciate it, thanks.

```
// package.json
// dependencies
    "firebase": "^7.5.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
// devDependencies
    "@firebase/firestore-types": "^1.9.0",
    "@firebase/testing": "^0.16.6",
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
```

Comment: People typically don't combine `firebase` and `firebase-admin` in the same code.  It's typically `firebase` for frontend web app and `firebase-admin` for backend node apps.

Comment: @DougStevenson That is very helpful, I'm working on removing `firebase` from this section of the project. Any idea why `admin.firestore.query` seems to match the expect by instance name but still fail the test?